# How to share content directly via a mobile application when a share button is clicked in a mobile browser?

Tags: jquery

We are trying to create sharing widget that has multiple social media channels (Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, LinkedIn, etc...).
When an item is shared via a desktop browser, it behaves like any other sharing widget.
But when an item is shared via a mobile browser, if the application is installed, it should be launched instead of opening a dialog in the mobile browser.
Is there such a widget? If not, how can we create this behavior? Or is this mobile browser dependent?

Answer (score 0):

Show only the sharing widget on the desktop version, and then if you want logic in place to control whether it launches the application (or whatever the other option is, sharing?) you'll have to write that yourself.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) has classes that hide and show mobile/desktop content in case you aren't familiar with CSS. As far as the mobile sharing stuff goes, I'd poke around the [Facebook Application API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app), there's a chance that the mobile behavior you're looking for is already there. You could also try [Google](http://google.com).